# click handler not firing in chrome after css transition

Tags: jquery, css

I have two divs that alternate/flip sides using a css transition.

```
transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ($cube-height*1.7);
```

I have a click handler that applies to both divs, however only the first one triggers the event.

```
$('.cube-face').on('click',function(){
    window.location = ($(this).attr('data-draw-link'));
});
```

I have created [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cp4vxvoj/) to demonstrate this, the click handler simply show an alert window.
I have read similar questions but am yet to find a solution to this problem. I have tried changing back-face-visibility and perspective but without success.

How do I get the click handler to fire for the second div?

This bug occurs in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use click on parent element, and compare "e.target" with "this".

```
//go to this draws results on click
$('#resultsFlipper').on('click',function(e){
    if(e.target == this){
        alert("green");
    } else {
        alert("red");
    }
});
```

[here is your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cp4vxvoj/2/)

Comment: thanks for that. your solution works in chrome, but now not in firefox!

Comment: you can use "e.target.tagName" or other properties for comparison. could be helpful.